# Notepad++ How to paste string across multiple lines

Tags: notepad++

`Alt`+`Shift`+`DownKey` to box-select beginning of each string followed by `Ctrl`+`V` pastes only on the first line.

Expected behavior: paste my string on all selected lines.

Using Notepad++ v5.9

Comment: Did my second answer workout for you?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1) Mark

2) Push `Alt+c` to open `Column editor`

3) Enter text there

### EDIT

As commented by @chapo it now works fine with `Alt-Shift-Down` and then pasting.

Comment: It pastes on the first line and removes the character on all other lines.

Comment: Hmm, thought I tested that. Well I added a new and this time working solution. :-)

Comment: This solution does not work. The one below does on the other hand. Not sure why this was selected as the answer.

Comment: @chapo just tested and it still works. Note that it is about `pasting`. Alt+Shift+Down and typing works but will not solve pasting.

Comment: @Daniel Alt+Shift+Down and `pasting` works just fine for me. Might be a version issue though as I am using 6.5.4. But this bug is definitely fixed in subsequent versions (after 5.9)

Comment: You need to copy the text with Alt+Shift+Selection, then Ctrl+C that, and then do what this answer says. You need to copy text as a column, if you copy text the normal way this doesn't work.

Comment: In addition: if you're trying to add to end of lines (differing sizes) or to multiple areas that do not line up, you can use mouse (CTRL+Left Click) to highlight each spot - then type text (or) hit Alt-C to add insertion.

Comment: this works only if you have to insert a single string, but if you have to paste an entire column, it will work only from Notepad to Notepad...

Answer (score 2):

Can you select your column with Alt+Shift+Down, type in a single unique character then use Search+Replace to get your text inserted the way you want?

Comment: This is not entirely correct either. You can select your column with Alt+Shit+Down and then just type whatever you want t insert. No need for the Search+Replace.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to copy the text you want to paste to notepad, then select the text you want to paste with Alt+Shift+Down in notepad. Then follow the guideline above and select the area with Alt+Shift+Down and then paste . It is probably not a version issue. @Rombus gave the correct answer in the comment.