# Notepad++ How do I insert a column of data?

Tags: replace, notepad++, paste

So I am trying to take a column of text data and replace that data with edited information. I am trying to manipulate values in a fixed width file. I want to leave the rows intact. I know I can hold ALT and select a whole column of information but when I try to paste into the selected area Notepad++ just adds the information above the first row and deletes the column Ive selected. Please help, I have been researching for a while now and cant find anything on this.

Below I will try to explain a bit better, if I were to select the asterisks using Alt+mouse and I have a column of data that I have copied from another file how could I replace the asterisks but leave the other data intact?

1111122222**22233333333333

1111122222**22222223333333

1111111122**22222223333333

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865957/notepad-how-to-paste-string-across-multiple-lines

Comment: @Derek, I think it's not, because here it asks to *paste* into the column, while the older question asked to add new column using the ALT+C menu

Comment: @psxls - you might be right.  I read the original question here as, "how do you paste the same text into each line."  But it looks like the OP is really wanting to paste multiple lines worth of stuff into the multi-line selection.

Answer (score 123):

If I understand the question correctly, you have copied the column of data from somewhere else and want to copy it as a column into notepad++. If you simply select a column in your notepad++ document and try to replace it with the external column, you will get many copies of that column. The trick is to first paste your column into an empty document (or into new lines in an existing document), then select that column you just pasted in but make sure you select it in column mode, i.e., while holding down the Alt key, and then copy it with Ctrl-C. Now you can column-select the column you want to replace and copy in your copied column with Ctrl-V

Comment: Work great, this actually what i want!!! I should learn this technique 15 years ago! and i always need this technique ! thanks you!

Comment: God bless you Sir.

Comment: we should notify this to Notepad++ Team, the column Paste mode should work directy from outside (like from Excel, by eg....) like it works from N++ to N++...

Comment: The bit about having to paste into an empty document is incorrect (or maybe this functionality has changed since); this works fine in the same document. As @gpanich's mostly ignored answer first pointed out, the important part is that you need to block-select (column-select via Alt) both the source text and the destination.

Answer (score 20):

You can use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + Mouse to select the columns to copy the data and replace it. This animated gif is self explanatory.

[image]

Comment: GIF: better than thousand words

Comment: how you record the screan?~

Comment: ShareX is a great software that not only captures image, but also creates animated gif files. (https://getsharex.com/)

Answer (score 13):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to paste a certain text in front of all columns you've selected ?

1. Either use ALT + Mouse or SHIFT + ALT + up/down arrow to select the desired number of columns.
2. Either use ALT + C or Menu Edit -> Column Editor to enter the Column Editor.
3. Fill in the "Text to Insert" and press Ok.

Good luck !

Edit: as pointed out in the comment, this is actually answered in [Notepad++ How to paste string across multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865957/notepad-how-to-paste-string-across-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 4):

ALT+Mouse works alright for me. I was able to replace the asterisks with other charactes. Maybe we have diferent versions? I don't think so, though.

Make sure you are also using Alt+Mouse when you select the information you want to copy. Not only when you paste it.

I hope that helps you.

Good luck!

Comment: This was the first answer with the key bit of information, i.e. that you have to block-select the source text to be copied, not just the destination where you want to paste.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing a column with new data is easy:

1. Hold ALT + select with your mouse the column (you already did that)
2. Press DELETE or CTRL + X to remove the old column
3. Leave the cursor flickering in the same position (or wherever you want to add the new column)
4. Paste CTRL + V

Note: you must NOT have your column selected when pasting. I think that's what confused you.

Answer (score 0):

Copy required text(columns) with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> and mouse (or arrows), then paste as required with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.