# How to replace column of values with another column of values in notepad++

Tags: replace, notepad++, paste

How to replace column of values with another column of values in notepad++
For example , Let's say I have file 1 contents as below

```
name2.address2.age.location
name3.address5.age.location
name1.address1.age.location
name4.address4.age.location
```

and I want to replace address column with the new values from another file

```
A123
234
5678
adafsffsafasfa
```

so that my replaced contents look like this

```
name2.A123.age.location
name3.234.age.location
name1.5678.age.location
name4.adafsffsafasfa.age.location
```

I tried Alt+c and alt+shift combination, but that didn't help. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe write a small program which uses `regex` to do the same?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321916/notepad-how-do-i-insert-a-column-of-data

Comment: Cinout, regex wich comes to my mind will work on single value. Ton Plooij, that solution is pasting the single value in single column. While I want to replace single column with multiple values.

Comment: Why not show us what you've tried, so that it can be improved?

Comment: CinCout, I tried the linux way "awk -F. 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{$2=a[FNR]}1' "... but I want windows solution. In notepad++ I selected the couln using "Alt+Shift+Down" key and replaced it with ABC using "Alt+C" combination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was playing around and I accidentally discovered the solution to my problem.
To replace a column follow the steps below:

```
1. Select the column using "`Shift + Alt + Down`" key combination 
2. Then delete the column by pressing the "`Delete`" key.
3. Select "new" column using "`Shift + Alt + Down`" key combination
4. Do the `drag` while holding down the `Alt` key.
```

Attached is the animation for better clarity. 
[image]
`Alt drag` can be used for even shifting the column positions as well